# complete installation proess for drupal 7.15 and ubercart-7.x-3.0

Tags: ubercart

I install drupal 7.15 and working successfully. After that i add ubercart-7.x-3.0 module. enabled product and store module but cant enable cart and order. how to enable cart and order. I am the beginner of drupal and ubercart. please help me

Answer (score 1):

**Note:** This is an alternative way by using [Drupal commerce](https://drupal.org/project/commerce) module and not the [Ubercart](http://drupal.org/project/ubercart) module.

As a beginner I'd suggest you should try the [Commerce Kickstart](http://drupal.org/project/commerce_kickstart) distribution first. It includes the latest versions of Drupal core, Drupal Commerce, and the other modules it depends on.  You can explore Drupal after that ;)

Just make sure you select the Commerce profile while installing (see screenshot)
[image: snap1]
And also create the example content after configuring the site
[image: snap2]

Comment: The OP is talking of Ubercart.

Comment: @kiamlaluno Yes, but the OP also seems to be confused how to start exploring Drupal as he mentioned he is beginner in Drupal and Ubercart. I just offered an alternative way for doing it ;-)

Comment: You should make it clear you are referring to a different module, or the OP is going to be confused about not seeing the setting pages s/he saw before.

Comment: @kiamlaluno thank you for the tip! I've edited the post :)